# Activation function for tensorflow DNNCalssifier's hidden layers

Tags: tensorflow-estimator, activation-function

It's possible to customize output layer's activation function for tensorflow's DNNClassifier canned estimator but no documentation about hidden layer's default activation function... Is it a ReLu one ? Is it customizable ?

Comment: Is it not only output layer ??

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the hidden layer's activation function by assigning new activation function to the `activation_fn` argument  when you instantiate `DNNClassifier`.

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,  # default value is relu
                                        n_classes=3,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/model")
```